# How to change Local History Default Path In Sublime Text 3 Package Local Histroy

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I change the default path in the Sublime Text 3 Local History package settings file please?

```
{
"history_retention": 0, // number of days to keep files, 0 to disable deletion
"format_timestamp": "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", // file_name-XXXXXXXX.file_extension
"history_on_close": true, // only save LocalHistory after closing a file, not when original was saved 
"history_on_focus_lost": false,
"history_on_load": true,
"history_path": "D:/historysublime", // redirect '~/.sublime/Local History/...' to some other place if "portable": false
"portable": true, // save to 'Sublime Text/Data/.sublime/Local History/...' instead of '~/.sublime/Local History/...'
"file_size_limit": 4194304 // 4 MB
}
```

I've tried to change but could not